# Loading Widget in HTML with Param from Browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a widget that I have hosted. I am able to successfully call it, and it loads. But When I am trying to pass it params from browser its not loading. The main difference is how I am calling the script.

The following code works but then its hard coded params

```js
<div id="idealy_widget"></div>
  <link href="https://xxxxxxxx/jscript/index.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <script id="widget-params" src="https://xxxxxxxxx/jscript/index.js" 
  clientId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
  clientSecret="xxxxxxxxxx" 
   username="xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    product_id="xxxxxxxxxx" type="module">
</script>
```

The following code doesnt work. it doesnt show the form which is part of the widget. It print the params.

```js
    <div id="idealy_widget"></div>
  <script type="module">
    const clientId = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('clientId');
    const clientSecret = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('clientSecret');
    const username = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('username');
    const product_id = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('product_id');
    
    console.log('Params:', clientId, clientSecret, username, product_id);

    const widgetScript = document.createElement('script');
    widgetScript.src = `https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/jscript/index.js?clientId=${clientId}&clientSecret=${clientSecret}&username=${username}&product_id=${product_id}`;
    widgetScript.type = 'module';
    widgetScript.id = 'widget-params';

    widgetScript.onload = () => {
      console.log('Script loaded successfully');
      // You may not need to manually call initWidget since it's called internally in index.js
    };

    document.head.appendChild(widgetScript);
  </script>
```

so in my app.js which i have the is

```html
<LocalizedModal clientId={clientId} clientSecret={clientSecret} username={username} product_id={product_id} /> and then in index.js    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // Get the parameters from the HTML script tag
  const scriptElement = document.getElementById('widget-params');
  const clientId = scriptElement.getAttribute('clientId');
  const clientSecret = scriptElement.getAttribute('clientSecret');
  const username = scriptElement.getAttribute('username');
  const product_id = scriptElement.getAttribute('product_id');
  // const ideaIds = scriptElement.getAttribute('ideaIds');
 

  // Render the React component with the parameters.
  const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('idealy_widget'));
  root.render(
    <App
      clientId={clientId}
      clientSecret={clientSecret}
      username={username}
      product_id={product_id}
      // ideaIds={ideaIds}
 
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The following code doesnt work.

That's probably because you made it do something completely different, than what the original code contained.

```
widgetScript.src = `https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/jscript/index.js?
    clientId=${clientId}&clientSecret=${clientSecret}&username=
    ${username}&product_id=${product_id}`;
```

You are adding all those parameters to the script URL here - but that is not what was in the original code. In that, these were set as *attributes* on the `script` element - so presumably, you need to add them to your dynamically added script element, in exactly the same way. (Unless you found it documented somewhere, that this was *also* supposed to work the same way, with URL parameters?)

```
const widgetScript = document.createElement('script');
widgetScript.src = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/jscript/index.js';
widgetScript.type = 'module';
widgetScript.id = 'widget-params';
widgetScript.setAttribute('clientId', clientId);
widgetScript.setAttribute('clientSecret', clientSecret);
widgetScript.setAttribute('username', username);
widgetScript.setAttribute('product_id', product_id);
```

Comment: if i use the above code, the widget doesnt display on the browser.

Comment: Then you'll probably have to give us a proper example of such a widget, and ideally link to whatever documentation might exist for it, as well. The code as shown _should_ create the equivalent of the static element you had, dynamically - but without knowing the details of how this widget works, it is not possible to tell why it doesn't work.

Comment: so in my app.js which i have the is <LocalizedModal clientId={clientId} clientSecret={clientSecret} username={username} product_id={product_id} /> and then in index.js

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is how to transform params form a script typeof module

```js
//   jscript/index.js
console.log(import.meta.url)
//   output: http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.js?clientId=x&clientSecret=xx&username=xxx&product_id=xxxx
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script id="widget-params" src="https://xxxxxxxxx/jscript/index.js?clientId=x&clientSecret=xx&username=xxx&product_id=xxxx" type="module">
  </script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: I dont understand this. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Sorry, my english is not very good, I guess you want  transform params form html  to a script (you call it widget )?

Comment: same here, english not my first lang hah :)  I want to take parameters from the URL, and then pass them into the widget (which is the script)

Comment: I added some more details. I am building the script and then calling it with the params. i need the params to come from the URL in the browser.

Comment: I know the problem when you add the widget,just remove document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'), because DOMContent had been loaded when this scrip run,you can get document Object directly

Answer (score 0):

from the index.js I removed the AddEventListener. and that worked. This is the code in the HTML

```html
<div id="idealy_widget"></div>
<script  >
  const clientId = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('clientId');
  const clientSecret = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('clientSecret');
  const username = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('username');
  const product_id = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('product_id');

  const widgetScript = document.createElement('script');
widgetScript.src = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxx/jscript/index.js';
widgetScript.type = 'module';
widgetScript.id = 'widget-params';
widgetScript.setAttribute('clientId', clientId);
widgetScript.setAttribute('clientSecret', clientSecret);
widgetScript.setAttribute('username', username);
widgetScript.setAttribute('product_id', product_id);

document.body.appendChild(widgetScript);

</script>
```